# Let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary sets. Show that $|A\times B|=|B\times A|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Not sure how to approach this, other than to say the following:

> Let $|A|$=n, and let $|B|=m$.
>   $$|A\times B|=n\cdot m$$
>   $$|B\times A|=m\cdot n$$
>   By the laws of commutativity for multiplication, $n\cdot m=m\cdot n$, and therefore $|A\times B|=|B\times A|$.

It feels too easy though. Am I missing something or is that about it?

Comment: You're assuming $A,B$ finite by letting their cardinalities be some pair of numbers $n,m$. What if they are infinite?

Comment: @agent154:  Are you still needing help with this, or did you figure it out from the hints?

Comment: @tarab Sorry - I did get it. Just forgot to accept'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the sets are arbitrary then you can't assume they are finite. You need to work here with the definition of cardinality.

To show that $|A\times B|=|B\times A|$ you must prove there exists a bijection $f:A\times B\to B\times A$. There is a very natural choice for such a function, when you think about what these sets are. (Be careful in case one of the $A$ or $B$ is empty.)

Comment: There is no need to be careful when $A$ or $B$ is empty. The obvious definition works, and just becomes vacuous.

Comment: yes, you and I know that, but the unwary need to realize something becomes vacuous ;)

Answer (score 5):

It might be the case that the sets are infinite. It is easier to find a bijection between $A\times B$ and $B\times A$.

I won't give hints here, because it'd be impossible to give a hint without giving away the bijection.